# Python 2.7 class method assignment oddity - lambda gets the behavior I want

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have the following Python 2.7 code:

```
from collections import namedtuple

Point = namedtuple('Point',['x','y'])
Point2 = namedtuple('Point2',['x','y'])

Point._revert = tuple
Point2._revert = lambda s: tuple(s)

for pointClass in [Point,Point2]:
    instance = pointClass(x=10,y=20)
    print "{} reverts to {}".format(instance,instance._revert())
```

The output is;

```
Point(x=10, y=20) reverts to ()
Point2(x=10, y=20) reverts to (10, 20)
```

So, what about the lambda is making the Point2._revert call work?

---

A simpler, standalone, example, requiring no imports:

```
class A(tuple):

    fTuple = tuple
    fLambda = lambda s: tuple(s)


a = A((1,2))

print repr(a.fTuple())
print repr(a.fLambda())
```

Comment: So, read [this](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#functions-and-methods). Essentially, function objects are descriptors which bind the instance as the first argument to the function, class objects are not descriptors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The brief answer is that the lambda implements the method `__get__`:

```
>>> (lambda s: tuple(s)).__get__
<method-wrapper '__get__' of function object at 0x101a37b90>
```

See the [descriptor documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html) for what this means, but basically, when the value stored in an attribute has a `__get__` method, reading that attribute returns the result of the `__get__` method on the value, not the value itself.

So, in the code:

```
globalLambda  = lambda s: tuple(s)

class A(object):
    attrLambda = globalLambda

a = A()
print globalLambda # --> <function <lambda> at 0x102137b90>
print A.attrLambda # --> <unbound method A.<lambda>>
print a.attrLambda # --> <bound method A.<lambda> of <__main__.A object at 0x102134790>>
```

these are three different things.

Since `tuple` is a `type` object, it has no `__get__` method, the access `a.fTuple` just returns `tuple`.

Answer (score 2):

`tuple` is a class, that does not require a parameter to be constructed.

Calling `instance.tuple()` returns `tuple()` which is just an empty tuple.

The difference with your anonymous function is that it is a function. When calling a class function from outside of the functional scope using `instance.function()`, `self` is automatically passed in as a parameter. Classes don't have this same treatment.

What's passed in is `._revert(instance)`, which calls `tuple(instance)` which actually reverts your tuple.

```
from collections import namedtuple

Point = namedtuple('Point',['x','y'])
Point2 = namedtuple('Point2',['x','y'])


class test:
    def __init__(self):
        print(self)

def func(a):
    print(a)


Point._revert = test
Point2._revert = func

instance = Point(x=10,y=20)
instance._revert()
>>><__main__.test object at 0x0000020ECAE1DFD0>

instance = Point2(x=10,y=20)
instance._revert()
>>>Point2(x=10, y=20)
```

Comment: So, when I call instance.f(), somehow the call inspects the value of instance.f, and decided whether to pass instance to f as an argument?

Comment: Requiring a parameter is not the difference. If you used a class that required a parameter, the class wouldn't receive the parameter.

Comment: the difference is that `tuple()` is a class and that self is not passed into classes

Comment: @user2357112 alright i edited it to make it a bit more clear what i was trying to say

Comment: @ThomasAndrews the difference is that functions are *descriptors* with a `__get__` method that does the instance binding. This is why you can call methods on instances like `my_instance.my_method()` even though you defined your method with `def my_method(self): ...` This is how methods work.

Comment: Thanks, @juanpa.arrivillaga, that is much clearer. I've written an answer which reflects this comment.